# Clarification on retrieval of Distinct rows based on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a table - T1 with id, Title, Firstname, postalcode

Second table - T2 with id, Title and PostalCode.

id is the primarykey in T1 and id is corresponding foreign key in T2.
Now i want to list out the Title from T1, Title from T2 and their id's for the matching id between T1 and T2.

BUT THE MAIN thing is only distinct column values of Title and their correspoding tables T1 and T2 along with their id should be displayed. 
For example, If a value 'Mr' is found and if second time if it is found, the value shouldnt be listed again.

Hope iam clear. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The Example is a little convoluted, but i think i understand the question.

you will like want to use the Distinct key word:

SELECT DISTINCT T1.Title
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT T2.Title
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id

This should grab distinct titles from T1 and T2. I hope this is what you were looking for, if not please describe what you are looking for as far as results a little bit more clearly, if you could add a table view that would be ideal.

Thanks,

~Madullah

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE() function could be your friend here.